# Typing a function that takes object with functions and binds them to the object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm typing this function for this weird library I'm writing for fun, and it takes an input object with methods and maps the methods to an output object whose methods call the input methods, but with the output object as the first parameter.

For example, turning this

```js
{ f(thing, x, y) { ... } /* g()... */ }
```

to this:

```js
thing = { f(x, y) { return (input object).f(thing, x, y); } }
```

I've typed it like this in typescript 5.0.1-rc (for the const generic)

```js
export type Thing<T extends Record<string, (thing: Thing<T>, ...args: any[]) => unknown>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (thing: Thing<T>, ...args: infer Args) => infer Return ? (...args: Args) => Return : never
};

declare function thingdoer<const T extends Record<string, (thing: Thing<T>, ...args: any[]) => unknown>>(input: T): Thing<T>;
```

and so this is nice and all if I do something like this,

```js
thingdoer({ f() { ... } }).f();
```

but when I get it to take arguments,

```js
thingdoer({ f(thing) { ... } }).f();
```

the signature of `f()` becomes `(...args: any[]) => unknown`, which I would rather not have happen.

EDIT: changing the generic constraints to `object` kinda works but the type of the `thing` parameter is now `any` so idk

EDIT: [this related?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)